# How to sort (and then remove duplicates) in python csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I think that after having tried tens of code blocks on this topic, my mistake should be elsewhere. The indentation looks right to me. The logic of the code also. Can you see anything that could fix it?

I suppose that I should sort the file first and only then remove the duplicates, which code will be added later as sorting seems the basis of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for your input.

```
# SECTION 2.A: save current search to second csv file (permanently as a backup
saving_current_search = input("Would you like to save your search? Type [y]/[n]: ")
if saving_current_search == 'y':
    # copy file1 to file2
    with open('list.csv', 'r') as reader, open('list-history.csv', 'a') as writer:
        for row in reader:
            writer.write(row)

    # sort permanent backup
    with open('list.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        sort = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        for eachline in sort:
            print(eachline)
```

=== UPDATE ======

I managed to sort but not to the right place. It printed on the stdout only. I just wanted to save the list-history.csv but it doesn't work. I used `writer.writerow(row)` though.

```
with open('list.csv', 'r', newline='') as in_file, open('list-history.csv', 'a', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    seen = set()  # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for row in reader:
        row = tuple(row)
        if row in seen: continue  # skip duplicate
            seen.add(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

=== LAST UPDATE =======

I know why I'm having this issue. I'm having a design issue. From the displayed code, you can't see it. But I have one file ('list-history.csv') opened twice. The first time I open it, I insert all the text I need in that file with append option 'a'. The second time, I open this same file to sort it and then use write option 'w'. I'm looking into this issue.

The issue appears on the next use of the script: the write 'w' used previously has overwritten the file. I think this is the explanation of my current issue.

Comment: if you can use pandas - open your csv in a dataframe, sort your frame and call dataframe.drop_duplicates() then save the frame back to a csv file . https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: My idea is to go from my code. I tried pandas too and the code won't run either. Sorry, I couldn't enumerate all I've done in the post. It may not be a code issue also but a logical error, maybe. What I get is...nothing happening when trying to sort.

Comment: What’s wrong with the current code? Can you share some example data? Why not use the csv module?

Comment: @AMC. Please see the update.

Comment: @timotom I’m pretty sure the code after the continue statement is inaccessible. Also, that barely addresses one part of my comment, no?